# Embed Custom UITableViewCell within another custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a list of custom `UITableViewCells`. The cell has text, which is sometimes long. I am truncating that at 2 lines in the table.

When a user touches the cell, I want to create a `UIView` as a popup with the exact same information as the `UITableViewCell`, with the addition of a header above the `UITableViewCell` content. So, essentially, I want something like the following:
[image]

I have built `VersePopupView` just as indicated in the picture, where the text "Custom Header" is actually a UILabel. I have instantiated the view from the XIB file and successfully set the UILabel text, but the custom `UITableViewCell` doesn't show, even though I have assigned that value as well. My `IBOutlet`s are all hooked up to IB.

Here is my instantiation:

```
        let popupView: VersePopupView = VersePopupView.instanceFromNib()
        popupView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100)
        popupView.assignVerseTableViewCell(cell: cell)

        window.addSubview(popupView)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And here is my VersePopupView class:

```
class VersePopupView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell: VerseTableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    class func instanceFromNib() -> VersePopupView {
        return UINib(nibName: "VersePopupView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! VersePopupView
    }


    func assignVerseTableViewCell(cell: VerseTableViewCell)
    {
        // Assign it
        self.cell = cell

        // Get the verse details
        if let verseDetails = cell.verse_details {

            self.title.text = verseDetails.verseReference()

            // Adjust the frame

            // Adjust the text to be attributed text

            // Set the title to the verse reference

            // Anything else?

        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong such that the UITableViewCell isn't showing up?

Is there a better pattern for this rather than embedding the UITableViewCell?

I don't want to duplicate code (which I have done in the past), because I want the user to interact with the popup just like they would in the table cell.

Comment: Don't try to use a table view cell outside a table view...

Comment: @matt - why not? What pattern should I use, then? How can I avoid duplicating all of the UI elements and interactions with those elements? I can display the `UITableViewCell` as a popup by itself just fine. If I didn't need the additional header, I'd be good. But I need the header as well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the "interactions". This is not a view controller's view, so you can't connect to anything outside it. Anyway, if it were me, I'd have a view xib and plop its view into the cell's content view and into the other view.

Comment: Or even have the view live inside the cell xib and just pull it out as desired.

Comment: You're thinking about it backwards. Create a UIView subclass that looks the way you want, then embed that in the table cell and use it in the pop up.

Comment: @Kevin I believe that's what I said. And what I did in my answer.

Comment: @matt - I agree. I'm working on changing this now. Really was just thinking of it backwards. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to convince you of how easy this is to do without trying to misuse a table view cell, so here's a screen shot:

[image]

You just have to believe me when I say that that's a three-row table followed by a totally independent ordinary view plucked from the inside of the table view cell (by loading the cell nib).

They not only look identical, they act identical; the view is a custom UIView subclass with an action method from the switch, and when I click the switch, it triggers that action method, both within the table and in the view outside it.

The view was designed entirely in the nib, and absolutely no code was repeated.

That seems to be the sort of thing you want to do. So, I encourage you, don't misuse table view cells; do this with an ordinary view that can live happily inside a cell or outside it.

Comment: If I'm building this through IB, is there a way to get the custom view to show up when I add that custom view to the table view cell prototype in IB?

Comment: That is what I did. I designed the custom view _in_ the cell. I think I said that in my answer... and it does show up.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to use it in two places and have it show up in both places in IB, without having to duplicate. So sure, wherever I develop the UI, everything will be visible. But when I try to add that new view into another view, none of the labels or images are there. I can assign the class to `MyCustomView` but none of the fields are in IB in that new view.

Comment: Ah. Well, I'm not sure what you think being able to see all the subviews inside IB would get you; it's not the running app, it's IB. The running app does exactly what you want, so the problem, I claim, is solved. Nevertheless, if you make this an IBDesignable view and add the subviews in code in the right way, you can have your cake and eat it too. But personally I wouldn't bother; I think you're wasting you time on the cake's icing when you should be paying attention to the batter. (I think I've carried that metaphor beyond its limits.)

Comment: I appreciate the help. I figured out why IB wasn't updating--needed to implement init (coder) and instantiate from XIB from there. (I was already using IBDesignable, but that wasn't working.) Did I absolutely *need* to? No, but I really wanted to see it inline--helps me designing things around it. I hit a number of other problems, but that's because doing it this way was new--I've worked through all of those, and this was the correct solution. Thank you for your help.